# Finding intervals where f is increasing

Tags: calculus

I know how do to this normally but this problem is tricky.

I'm given the derivative $f'(x)=(x+1)^2(x-3)^5(x-6)^4$ and I need to find the increasing intervals.

I set the derivative equal to 0:

$0=(x+1)^2(x-3)^5(x-6)^4$

I realize I can just pull out the critical points:

$x=-1, x=3, x=6 $

And then construct the intervals:

$(-\infty, -1)\cup(-1, 3)\cup(3, 6)\cup(6, \infty)$

---

To find if each interval is increasing or decreasing, I'd normally plug a value that's between each interval into the derivative to see if it's positive or negative, but I suspect things might be more tricky here since other examples I've found construct a table with intervals and binomials, but I haven't been able to grasp what those examples are doing. I'm mostly looking for some direction.

Comment: Only root $x = 3$ is relevant because it's the only point the derivative changes its sign.

Comment: A polynomial is continuous and it has finitely many zeros. Therefore, its sign will be constant between consecutive zeros. This means that your method of evaluating at a point inside each of those intervals will tell you the sign of the values on all the points of each interval. The sign of $f'$ tells you the monotonicity of $f$. So, your plan works and it is justified.

Answer (score 0):

We have that since $(x+1)^2$ and $(x-6)^4$ are both $\ge 0$ the singn for $f'(x)$ depends only upon $(x-3)$ therefore

$$f'(x)\ge 0 \quad\text{for} \quad  x\ge3$$